# Density of ends of long words in a hyperbolic group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a Gromov hyperbolic group with a generating set $S$. For each $g \in G$, let $\xi_g$ be the point in the ideal boundary corresponding to the sequence $(g^n)$. Let $l_S(g)$ be the word length of $g$ w.r.t. the generating set $S$.

I would like to know how dense the following set is on the ideal boundary of $G$ (denote by $\partial G$);
 $$ E_L := \{ \xi_g : l_S(g) \le L \} $$
More precisely, is the set $E_L\quad$ $e^{-\alpha L}$-dense in $\partial G$ for some positive number $\alpha$? If so, for which $\alpha$? I suspect there is some relation between the optimal $\alpha$ and the Hausdorff dimension of $\partial G$.. but not sure how I should investigate further.

Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Harry Baik: I believe this question should probably be tagged with 'gt.geometric-topology'. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @RicardoAndrade I added a tag, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing was worked out by Coornaert, who constructed Patterson--Sullivan measures on the boundaries of word-hyperbolic groups:

Michel Coornaert, Mesures de Patterson-Sullivan sur le bord d'un espace hyperbolique au sens de Gromov [Patterson-Sullivan measures on the boundary of a hyperbolic space in the sense of Gromov], Pacific J. Math. 159 (1993), no. 2, 241–270.

A nice account was given by Danny Calegari in [these notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0029).  I think you'll find what you need in there.

Comment: So, I'm not sure what you mean by '$e^{-\alpha L}$ dense', but Lemma 2.5.8 might be what you're looking for.